# Why does iBooks connect to the Internet whenever I copy/paste?

Tags: macos, applications, books

I am monitoring the Internet usage of my applications and I noticed that iBooks initializes a connection to 23.221.221.248:443 whenever I select some text and then copy it.

Does someone know why, or how can the actual contents of that connection be exposed?

Comment: That IP address belongs to akamai which hosts much of Apple's content and some of it's services. I don't have a solution on iOS, but if you have a computer or high end router, you might be able to set up a web proxy ([e.g. charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com)) to sniff the content of the message.

Comment: @bmike Alas, I tried and it's an SSL connection. The dummy certificate that Charles proxy uses to record SSL connections doesn't fool him and the connection fails

Comment: Bummer - orchestrating a man-in-the-middle attack will prove more challenging than sniffing port 80 :(